# Numerically stable algorithms for computing remainder of polynomials

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, polynomials

Let $f, g \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ and $\deg f > \deg g$. I am looking for asymptotically fast and *numerically stable* algorithms for computing $f \bmod g$. In the applications intended, both $f, g$ are dense polynomials with double precision floating-point coefficients. But, for now, I'm more interested in the algorithms rather than the implementation. References for algorithms for computing GCD of numerical polynomials are also appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the book by Dario Bini & Victor Pan: ["Polynomial and Matrix computations, Volume 1: Fundamental algorithms", ISBN 0-8176-3786-9,  Birkhäuser, 1994](http://books.google.be/books/about/Polynomial_and_matrix_computations.html?id=WbFxj-HvaGYC).